# Change last character in line with sed

Tags: sed

I have the following line in my .conf file

```
application.release = "4"
```

I'm trying change it to `application.release = "4.$any_value"` with sed

Current pattern:

```
sed -c -i "s/\(application.release *= *\).*/\1\"$any_value\"/"
```

Could help me anybody?

Comment: I presume {`any_value`|`app_version`} is just an editing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^application.release = "4"$/s/"$/.$any_value"/' file
```

If a line contains `application.release = "4"` replace the last character with `.$any_value"`

Comment: Hi @potong, Thanks. It helps

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one more backslash:

```
sed -c -i "s/\(application.release *= *\).*/\1\"\$app_version\"/"
```